# ng-admin , t.choice is not a function when trying to do some autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, ng-admin

I try to do an autocomplete field in ng-admin

got :

> Error: t.choices is not a function
>   r/<.compile/<.pre@http://admin.dev:81/bower_components/ng-admin/build/ng-admin.min.js:15:2543

etc ...

here is my code

45         var ingredientName = nga.entity('ingredient_names')

> 70           recipe.creationView().fields([
>   nga.field('title'),
>   nga.field('guest'),
>   nga.field('ingredients' , 'embedded_list')
>   .targetFields([
>   nga.field('measure').label('quantity'),
>   nga.field('ingredientName', 'reference')
>   .targetEntity(ingredientName)
>   .targetField(nga.field('name'))
>   .remoteComplete(true),
>   nga.field('unit','choices').choices([
>   {label : 'toto', value : 1}
>   ]).label('Unity')                                  ]),
>   nga.field('steps')                         ]);

Could you folks Help please ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed already, please use the latest version.

https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/issues/778